# Syntax error when using conditional rendering with prop of object

Tags: reactjs

I have seen many React tutorials with ternary, just like `{shown && <h2>Hai!<h2>}`.

Anyway, I got syntax error when trying to use prop of object as first expression (ex: `{status.shown && <h2>Hai!<h2>}`. Can someone explain this? I am using `create-react-app` boilerplate.

**EDIT:**

OK, I just realized that the error was happened inside `.map` loop. Here is my code.

```
{fields.map((field, key) => (
    {field.type === "checkbox" && (
        <Form.Checkbox
            key={key}
            name={field.name}
            label={field.label}
        />
    )}
    {field.type === "text" && (
        <Form.Input 
            key={key}
            name={field.name}
            type={field.type}
            label={field.label}
            placeholder={field.placeholder}    
        />
    )}
))}
```

It shows `Unexpected token, expected ,`

Comment: add ur entire component code

Comment: Preferably just the relevant parts

Comment: Also, what's the specific error?

Comment: It should work unless your status is null or undefined. In that case, you can use { status && status.shown && <h2>Hai!<h2> } or you are directly adding the code inside the return method, so you to wrap the component ex: return( <React.Fragment>{ status && status.shown && <h2>Hai!<h2> } </React.Fragment> );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's meant to be used inside JSX expression. You can wrap it around a `div` or `Fragment`:

```
{
  fields.map((field, key) => (
    <div>
      {field.type === 'checkbox' && (
        <Form.Checkbox key={key} name={field.name} label={field.label} />
      )}
      {field.type === 'text' && (
        <Form.Input
          key={key}
          name={field.name}
          type={field.type}
          label={field.label}
          placeholder={field.placeholder}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

In this case, it might be simpler to just use a switch or if statement instead:

```
{
  fields.map((field, key) => {
      if (field.type === 'checkbox') {
        return <Form.Checkbox key={key} name={field.name} label={field.label} />
      } 
      ...
```

If you only have 2 cases, you can use ternary operator:

```
{
  fields.map((field, key) =>
    (field.type === 'checkbox' ? (
      <Form.Checkbox key={key} name={field.name} label={field.label} />
    ) : (
      <Form.Input
        key={key}
        name={field.name}
        type={field.type}
        label={field.label}
        placeholder={field.placeholder}
      />
    )));
}
```

Comment: Got it, I prefer use if statement. The layout was strange when I'm using `div` wrap. Thanks.

Comment: A ternary operator might be more succinct if there's only 2 cases (see my edit), but it's personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

eg

```
{ field === "checkbox" && fields.map((field, key) => (<div>.....</div>))}
```

or

```
{ field === "checkbox" && shown && fields.map((field, key) => (<div>.....</div>))}
```

verification should occur before the map

or

```
{ fields.map((field, key) => (
<div>
 {field.type === "checkbox" && <div>....</div>}
</div>))
}
```